Gitgub repository set chmod 600 for one file
Hi I'm new to github and for more than 24 hours I can't find a solution to my problem.
I have a website which I have uploaded to Github and using Netlify as a web host.
However, the problem is that I need one file on my site to be inaccessible to the public but still available for my script to make the site work properly, aka the equivalent of chmod 600.
I've been trying to solve this for so long but haven't found a way to do it anywhere. I'm getting really desperate... I would be very grateful for any help.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
I tried setting my file in the github repository to chmod to 600, but that doesn't seem to work.
